# Is there another way for apps to stop being killed in the background?

Tags: adb, android-10, background-process

I have a android 10 and I have tried whitelisting the app and it didn't work, I tried `RUN_ANY_IN_BACKGROUND` that didn't work, and tried `WAKE_LOCK allow` that didn't work. Is there another way. Also, tried don'tkillmyapps that didn't work either.

FYI: I know the commands that I talked about looks incomplete I just typed it like that to make it shorter so you can get the gist of it.

Comment: https://dontkillmyapp.com

Comment: @Irfan Latif I tired that twice it don't it didnt work just kept saying 100 %